# Just installed GVim 8.2 but don't see the File, Edit, etc. menu items at the top of the window

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows

Newbie here, sorry.   I just installed GVim 8.2 on Windows 10 but I was expecting to see the familiar menu items at the top: File, Edit, etc. when I open GVim or edit a file.

I have seen them when using Vim on other computers (Windows also).

I followed another post that said to create a shortcut on the Desktop and run that but the result was the same.

Also, when I try open a file, instead of opening I get a GVim window that says 'Press ENTER or type command to continue'.   Once I press ENTER the file opens normally.

Is there a parm file setting I need to change or set?

Thanks very much!!

-gary

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you add more context, such as where you downloaded it from, how you installed it and so on? When you say "when I try to open a file", how are you opening it, using `:e`, or in another way? Feel free to attach screenshots if you can... You can drag & drop pictures into your post and Stack Exchange will add the appropriate markup... You can [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: Based on the "Press ENTER…" message I suspect something in the configuration files (*i.e.*, vimrc and vimruntime) might be out of wack. See for example [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.   I downloaded gvim_8.2.2825.exe from https://www.vim.org/download.php.  I created a shortcut on my Desktop and added that icon to my Taskbar.   When I click the icon the Vim GUI version opens with no 'File, etc.' headers.  Also if I right-click on a TXT file and select 'Edit' the same thing happens.  Where are the config files and how do I edit them to get the controls to appear.    Thanks again for all the help!!!

Comment: I followed the above link for debugging my vimrc file but it was no help.  Any other suggestions are most welcome.  I'm basically just trying to get the File, Edit,... menu back at the top of my edit window.  Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Thanks very much for the help folks!!

Comment: I resolved the issue by creating a $HOME environment variable as c:\vim and moving the vimrc file to that location.   When I started GVim the menu options were there.